# SQL Server : @@error on select from empty table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following SQL Server stored procedure. The issue is: when the `log_db_error` table has records, it works fine, but when table is empty `@@ERROR` picks up an error. Any way this can be resolved? Thanks in advance

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Log_DB_Error_Get_All]
    @rownum_min int,
    @rownum_max int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    WITH ORDERED_LIST AS
    (
        SELECT 
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY el.created_on ) AS ROWNUM, 
            el.log_db_error_id,
            el.[error_function],
            el.[error_message],
            el.[error_severity],
            el.[error_state],
            el.created_on,
            el.created_by
        FROM 
            log_db_error el
    )
    SELECT * 
    FROM ORDERED_LIST
    WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN @rownum_min AND @rownum_max;

    IF(@@ERROR <> 0)
    BEGIN
        GOTO Handle_Error
    END

    -- execution jumps here when (@@ERROR > 0), i.e. error happens
    Handle_Error:
        DECLARE @ERROR_MESSAGE  NVARCHAR(4000);
        DECLARE @ERROR_SEVERITY INT;
        DECLARE @ERROR_STATE    INT;
        DECLARE @ERROR_DATE     DATETIME;
        DECLARE @ERROR_FUNCTION NVARCHAR(100);
        DECLARE @ERROR_CREATED_BY   BIGINT;

        SELECT 
            @ERROR_MESSAGE = ERROR_MESSAGE(),
            @ERROR_SEVERITY = ERROR_SEVERITY(),
            @ERROR_STATE = ERROR_STATE(),
            @ERROR_DATE = SYSDATETIME(),
            @ERROR_CREATED_BY = null;

        SET @ERROR_FUNCTION = OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(@@PROCID) + '.' + OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID);

        --store error details to a log table
        exec dbo.Log_DB_Error_Insert @ERROR_FUNCTION, @ERROR_MESSAGE, @ERROR_SEVERITY, @ERROR_STATE, @ERROR_DATE, @ERROR_CREATED_BY
END
```

Comment: What is the error that is generated?

Comment: i think you are not showing full script.Also you should provide @@Error message from table.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to understand what @@Error does?

> @@Error will give you the error number for the last Transact-SQL
>   statement executed.

Your last T-Sql statement is

```
 SELECT * 
    FROM ORDERED_LIST
    WHERE ROWNUM BETWEEN @rownum_min AND @rownum_max;
```

I don't see any error in this statement so there is no error. And because of your If statement you are getting empty table.